# Mapping Rows Data to MyObject

Tags: c#, sql-server, automapper

i have my classes as the following:

```
class SalesInvlice
{
int id {get;set;}
string number {get;set;}
List<InvoiceItems> {get;set}
}

class InvoiceItems
{
id {get;set}
string item_name {get;set}
int price {get;set;}
}
```

my application is an agent that can connect to any database specified in the config file, and to execute a certain query. in my case it will execute a query on one client DB as the following `select id, number, items.id as items_id, item_name, price from transaction left join transaction_details on transactions.id = transaction_details.transaction_id`

let say i got the data using SQLDataReader, but i am open in another solutions as well.

what i am looking for here, is to map the results from SQLDataReader to list of SalesInvoice Object.

the issue i am facing that if the transaction has list of transaction_details, this means the datareader will get them to me in different rows.

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice to make you can return the data in one dataset or two. The first will return the transaction data duplicated see bellow. You will need to manage the dr duplicate transactions.

```
select id, 
    number, 
    items.id as items_id, 
    item_name, price 
from transaction 
    left join transaction_details 
         on transactions.id = transaction_details.transaction_id
```

Or return the data in two sets of data ( transaction and transaction detail). I am assuming that you are interested in data for a particular transaction not many different transactions. Ado.net will allow for multiple groups of data to be returned. You would need to cast each data set to is object type. dimly a case of newing up a transaction and assigning properties.

Comment: that is what i am trying to avoid, i want something a Mapper for example, it just do that for me.

Comment: sadly the Automapper.Data is the one i want, and it is beta, i tried it, it is not working perfectly yet. 

thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue, i have made my simi general mapper.

I have mapper that do the following:

```
    private List<T> mappingFun<T>( IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> args, object propListObj = null) where T: Entity
    {
        List<T> listObject = new List<T>();

        foreach(var arg in args)
        {
            T returnedObject = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            PropertyInfo[] modelProperties = returnedObject.GetType().GetProperties();

            var addedobject = listObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == arg[returnedObject.GetType().Name + "_name"].ToString());
            if (addedobject != null)
            {
                returnedObject = addedobject;
            }

            foreach(var prop in modelProperties)
            {
                var a = prop.PropertyType;
                if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(returnedObject, arg[returnedObject.GetType().Name + "_" + prop.Name].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    var propModuleObj = GetType().GetMethod("mappingFun", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>), typeof(object) }, null).MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Single()).Invoke(this, new object[] { new List<Dictionary<string, object>>() { arg }, prop.GetValue(returnedObject) });
                    prop.SetValue(returnedObject, propModuleObj);

                }
            }
            listObject.AddIfNotExist(returnedObject);
            if(propListObj != null)
                listObject.AddRange((List<T>)propListObj);
        }
        return listObject;
    }
```

This helps 100%

Comment: one issue of it, it is very slow.